# Show a new view when dismiss an AlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing for Cydia. There is a way to show a new view when an AlerView did dismiss with a index button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this delegate and put in what functionality you want -

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 0)
        NSLog(@"OK pressed");
    else if(alertView.tag == 1)
        NSLog(@"Cancel Pressed");
    return;
}
```

Make sure to put valid `tag` for the buttons for your `AlertView`...

**UPDATE:** To create a view programmatically, you can do this -

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
[yourSuperView addSubview:v];
[v release];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. But i wann know how can I create a view programmatically